# Laravel | Contact form with reply (autorespond to sender)

Tags: laravel

here is my ContactController function send:

```
public function send(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required'
        ]);

        Mail::send('pages.emails.contact-message', [ 
            'msg' => $request->message
        ], function($mail) use($request) {
            $mail->from($request->email, $request->name);

            $mail->to('mymail@example.com')->subject('Subject');
        });
        return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . "#contact")->with('flash_message', 'Thank you');
    }
```

at the moment it's a simple form handling, but I would like to enrich it with an email notification to the sender like "your message has been delivered". At the moment I only have a flash message. Could someone tell me how I can make such a reply to the sender?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you passing $request->email to the `from` method? Please take a look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#sending-mail)

Comment: $request->email is a input field in view